# Deafult constructor of template class and traversing

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, tree

I have a Node class and a Tree class and in my Tree class (which is a m-ary tree), I have a method that does an inorder traversal on my tree.
So the problem is that when I call this method, I am able to print the first branch of my tree and after that I get segmentation fault. I know (with debugging) that the error might come from some where in constructor of my Node class or maybe I didn't write a very good traversing method.
Here is my code.

**Node.hpp**

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> 

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
class Node {
private:
  V _data;
  Node<V, N>* _children[N];

  template <typename U, unsigned short M>
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const Node<U, M>&);

public:
  Node();
  Node(V);
  Node(V, unsigned short);
  Node(const Node&); // copy constructor
  Node& operator= (Node&); // assignement by copy constructor
  Node (Node&&); // transfer constructor
  Node& operator= (Node&&); // assignement by transfer constructor
  ~Node() = default;
  V getData() const;
  Node<V, N>* getChildren();
  void setChild(unsigned short, Node<V, N>*);
  void delChild(unsigned short);
  Node<V, N>* getChild(unsigned short); 
};

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>::Node()
  : _data(0),  _children(nullptr) {}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>::Node(V data)
  : _data(data) {
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    _children[i] = NULL;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>::Node(V data, unsigned short size)
  : _data(data) {
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    _children[i] = NULL;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>::Node (const Node& other)
  : _data(other._data) {
  // _children = other._children;
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    _children[i] = other._children[i];
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>& Node<V, N>::operator= (Node& n){
  if (&n != this) {
    delete _children;
    _data = n._data; _children = n._children;
    n._data = 0; n._children = nullptr;
  }
  return *this;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>::Node (Node&& n){
  _data = n._data; _children = n._children;
  n._data = 0; n._children = nullptr;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>& Node<V, N>::operator= (Node&& n){
  if (&n != this) {
    delete _children;
    _data = n._data; _children = n._children;
    n._data = 0; n._children = nullptr;
  }
  return *this; 
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N> // TO DO : move this to class scope ???
V Node<V, N>::getData() const {return _data;}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>* Node<V, N>::getChildren() {return *_children;}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
void Node<V, N>::setChild(unsigned short index, Node<V, N>* childNode){
  this->_children[index] = childNode;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
void Node<V, N>::delChild(unsigned short index){
  this->_children[index] = NULL;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>* Node<V, N>::getChild(unsigned short index){
  return &this->_children[index];
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Node<V, N>& node){
  if (node._data) o << node._data ;
  return o;
}

#endif
```

**tree.hpp**

```
#ifndef TREE_HPP
#define TREE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> 
#include "node.hpp"

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
class Tree {
private:
  Node<V, N>* _info;
public:
  Tree();
  Tree(Node<V, N>*);
  Tree(V, unsigned short);
  Tree(const Tree&) = delete;  // copy constructor
  Tree& operator= (const Tree&) = delete; // assignement by copy constructor
  Tree (Tree&&); // transfer constructor
  Tree& operator= (Tree&&); // assignement by transfer constructor
  ~Tree() {delete _info;}
  Node<V, N>* info();
  bool vide();
  bool ins(unsigned short, Node<V, N>*);
  bool del(unsigned short);
  Node<V, N>* fils(unsigned short);
  void inorderTraverse(Node<V, N>*);
};

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Tree<V, N>::Tree() 
  : _info(nullptr) {}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Tree<V, N>::Tree(Node<V, N>* newNode)
  : _info(newNode) {}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Tree<V, N>::Tree(V data, unsigned short size) {
  Node<V, N>* node = new Node<V, N>(data, size);
  _info = node;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Tree<V, N>::Tree(Tree&& t) {
  _info = t._info;
  t._info = nullptr;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Tree<V, N>& Tree<V, N>::operator= (Tree&& t) {
  if (&t != this) {delete _info; _info = t._info; t._info = nullptr;}
  return *this;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>* Tree<V, N>::info() { return _info;}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
bool Tree<V, N>::vide() {
  return true ? _info : false;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
bool Tree<V, N>::ins(unsigned short index, Node<V, N>* node){
  if (_info) {
    _info->setChild(index, node);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
bool Tree<V, N>::del(unsigned short index){
  if (_info) {
    _info->delChild(index);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>* Tree<V, N>::fils(unsigned short index){
  return &_info->getChild(index);
}

template <typename V, unsigned short N>
void Tree<V, N>::inorderTraverse(Node<V, N>* node){
  if (node->getData()){
    std::cout << *node << "\n";
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if (node->getChildren()[i].getData()){
        inorderTraverse(&node->getChildren()[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "tree.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"
#define SIZE 5
int main() {
  Node<char, SIZE> n1('A',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_1('B',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_2('C',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_3('D',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_1_1('E',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_1_2('F',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_1_1_1('G',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_2_1('H',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_2_1_1('I',SIZE);
  Node<char, SIZE> n1_3_1('J',SIZE);
  n1.setChild(0,&n1_1);
  n1.setChild(1,&n1_2);
  n1.setChild(2,&n1_3);
  n1_1.setChild(0,&n1_1_1);
  n1_1.setChild(1,&n1_1_2);
  n1_1_1.setChild(0,&n1_1_1_1);
  n1_2.setChild(0,&n1_2_1);
  n1_2_1.setChild(0,&n1_2_1_1);
  n1_3.setChild(0,&n1_3_1);
  Tree<char, SIZE> t(&n1);
  t.inorderTraverse(t.info());
  return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: not all of your nodes have 5 children so `node->getChildren()[i].getData()` crashes due to dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah I know that. But i am not able to fix it. I don't know where I have to modify. Could you please give me a hint if you know what to do?  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node::getChildren()` returns `*_children` which is the first pointer in the `_children` array. You then call `node->getChildren()[i]` which adds `i` to this pointer. This happens to work for the first node as you've laid all your nodes out next to each other on the stack so it returns the correct node. This is undefined behaviour and in real code with heap allocated nodes this would quickly crash. `getChildren` should be:

```
template <typename V, unsigned short N>
Node<V, N>** Node<V, N>::getChildren() { return _children; }
```

Then your calling code would be:

```
if (node->getChildren()[i]->getData()) {
   inorderTraverse(node->getChildren()[i]);
}
```

This then gets us back to the original cause of your crash due to dereferencing a null pointer. The simple fix here is to just check the child is not null:

```
auto children = node->getChildren();
if (children[i] && children[i]->getData()) {
   inorderTraverse(children[i]);
}
```

Your code will now crash on exit due to the `Tree` destructor deleting a node which is stack allocated:

```
~Tree() { delete _info; }
```

If you want to use `delete` all your nodes need to be created with `new` not stack allocated in `main`. Even better use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` and avoid `delete` completely.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and very detailed answer ... So I changed the destroctor to default because you are right and there isn't any allocation here. I have also a version of this code with allocation and the problem there is bit more complex.